# VSCode cannot find python (Anaconda install)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I have just installed anaconda3 5.2.0 with vscode 1.27.2 on windows10  (actually, removed and reinstalled) and am trying to execute the simplest python code on terminal.  However, I get the following errors...

> jac@p50:/mnt/c/Users/jac/Documents/dev/python/JupyterNotebooks/Learn/Pandas Learn$activate base
>   /mnt/c/Users/jac/Anaconda3/Scripts/activate: 2: /mnt/c/Users/jac/Anaconda3/Scripts/activate: cygpath: not found
>   /mnt/c/Users/jac/Anaconda3/Scripts/activate: 3: .: Can't open /etc/profile.d/conda.sh
>   jac@p50:/mnt/c/Users/jac/Documents/dev/python/JupyterNotebooks/Learn/Pandas Learn$
>   C:/Users/jac/Anaconda3/python.exe "c:/Users/jac/Documents/dev/python/JupyterNotebooks/Learn/Pandas Learn/hello1.py"
>   -bash: C:/Users/jac/Anaconda3/python.exe: No such file or directory

I do see the python.exe file at C:/Users/jac/Anaconda3/python.exe .  I also do not understand why terminal in bash.  I have used cygwin and installed ubuntu in my win10 machine.  I don't have extensive env setup experience, but really need to get vscode running to debug and need anaconda libraries (pandas) to get some work done.  Any help really appreciated.  Thanks,  John

Comment: I'm not sure if Anaconda supports cygwin, and by "installed ubuntu" do you mean WSL? Basically is there a reason you aren't just running Anaconda on Windows 10 directly?

Comment: Hi Brett, I was using cygwin before WSL was available.  Then I installed WSL.  I periodically need to use unix/linux tools to process really large files.  I did install Anaconda and was using it with np++ editor, but now see integrated debugging in vscode - which I really need, but due to all these installed tools, I can't even execute a single basic python program (although I can open a windows command line and execute the python program just fine). The way that vscode invokes the terminal and the program to be executed seems to be the problem, partly due to the  'activate base' command.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so the problem is that Anaconda + VSCode + WSL not playing nice.  I really don't have to run my python programs under WSL (bash.exe), so I changed the terminal>integrated>shell:windows value to C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe, and unticked the Activate environment option.  Now I can execute and debug!  :)