# What causes this error with hello.py in vscode for Windows: "-bash: C:/Python37/python.exe: No such file or directory"?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, visual-studio-code

When I click the *play* button to run my hello.py program in vscode, I get the following error in the terminal

```
PF1FEARB:~/tmp$ C:/Python37/python.exe c:/Users/xtn/hello.py
-bash: C:/Python37/python.exe: No such file or directory
```

Manually running the script in the terminal works

```
PF1FEARB:~/tmp$ python hello.py
Hello
```

My python.exe is installed here:

```
C:\Users\xtn\AppData\Local\bucache\cbdn10897X>where python
C:\Python37\python.exe
```

Vscode shows the following installed extension

```
Name: Python
Id: ms-python.python
Description: Linting, Debugging (multi-threaded, remote), Intellisense, Jupyter Notebooks, code formatting, refactoring, unit tests, snippets, and more.
Version: 2020.2.64397
Publisher: Microsoft
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python
```

How do I find out which PATH vscode uses to look for executables?

Comment: An extension with no new release after 2016 is not worth the while. Uninstall that one and try to use Microsoft's https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python

Comment: Replaced with the above extension, but the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to apply the same solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52583127/vscode-cannot-find-python-anaconda-install). I changed to PowerShell and it works for me now. Command palette -> Terminal: Select Default Shell -> select PowerShell. Restart vscode.

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure the Python interpreter correctly within the vscode editor window itself? You'll have to configure certain things within the IDE itself to run Python code through the editor window. Following the guide for setting up Python in vscode (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial), perhaps here are a few steps you missed:
1.

> install the Python extension for VS Code from the Visual Studio Marketplace. For additional details on installing extensions, see Extension Marketplace. The Python extension is named Python and it's published by Microsoft.

2.

> Select a Python interpreter:
>   Python is an interpreted language, and in order to run Python code and get Python IntelliSense, you must tell VS Code which interpreter to use.
>
> From within VS Code, select a Python 3 interpreter by opening the Command Palette (⇧⌘P), start typing the Python: Select Interpreter command to search, then select the command. You can also use the Select Python Environment option on the Status Bar if available (it may already show a selected interpreter, too):
>
> The command presents a list of available interpreters that VS Code can find automatically, including virtual environments. If you don't see the desired interpreter, see Configuring Python environments.
>
> Selecting an interpreter sets the python.pythonPath value in your workspace settings to the path of the interpreter. To see the setting, select File > Preferences > Settings (Code > Preferences > Settings on macOS), then select the Workspace Settings tab.
>
> Note: If you select an interpreter without a workspace folder open, VS Code sets python.pythonPath in your user settings instead, which sets the default interpreter for VS Code in general. The user setting makes sure you always have a default interpreter for Python projects. The workspace settings lets you override the user setting.

Comment: Where is python.pythonPath located in vscode on Windows?